# retain Timer value after I leave and comeback to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have bottom navigation bar and the activity hosts 4 fragments. I open fragment from scratch but one of the fragments has timer feature which I need to retain its value unless user explicitly turns it off. I started with savedInstance state but it takes a lot of work to maintain time counter in app closed scenario, so I am looking for an efficient solution. What should be my best strategy ?

Here is what I am doing to call fragments. Fragment named F3 is the one contains timer.

```
public class MainActivity() extends AppcompatActivity{


bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener((position, wasSelected) -> {

                if (position == 0) {
                    if (!wasSelected)
                        getFragmentByTag(F1.TAG);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    if (!wasSelected)
                        getFragmentByTag(F2.TAG);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    if (!wasSelected)
                        getFragmentByTag(F3.TAG);
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    if (!wasSelected)
                        getFragmentByTag(F4.TAG);
                return true;
            }
    );
}
```

Method to getFragment

```
private void getFragmentByTag(String tag) {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    BackHandledFragment fragment;
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        switch (tag) {
            case F1.TAG:
                fragment = new F1();
                break;
            case F2.TAG:
                fragment = new F2();
                break;
            case F3.TAG:
                fragment = new F3();
                break;
            case F4.TAG:
                fragment = new F4();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = null;
        }
    } else {
        fragment = (BackHandledFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }


    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }, 200);

}
```

Comment: did you tried setting some static int value for counter and then stopping on onStop and starting again onResume from the stored value ?.

Comment: I need to keep timer running until user explicitly stops, so pause to resume scenario will take time calculation every seconds and with static value it becomes inefficient..

Comment: Ok then you can use service in background and get notified through broadcasts for counter value and this will keep running even user has opened another app in between. So just start the intent service or just service as per need and push into to background with starting value and catch it back when you need through receivers.

Comment: any explanation for down vote??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your timer works exactly, but it looks like you can use timestamps.
When user turns on the time, you get timestamp (with yoda):

```
DateTime timestamp = new DateTime();
```

and save it somewhere in shared prefs/in activity/etc

Each time u need to show timer to user, you read this timestamp and MINUS it from currenttime and start UI timer from/to this timestamp (based on your logic)